# How to check if SQL schema allows NULL for a column?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, schema

Hi I have the following code which lists all column names for a given SQL table:

```
public static DataTable GetSQLTableSchema(string _connectionString,string _tableName) 
        {
            string connectionString = _connectionString;
            string tableName = _tableName.Trim();
            DataTable schemaTable = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader; 


            try {

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    string queryString = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;

                    using(SqlCommand queryCMD = new SqlCommand(queryString))
                    {
                        queryCMD.Connection = connection;
                        connection.Open();
                        sqlDataReader = queryCMD.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);
                        schemaTable = sqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable();
                        connection.Close();  
                    }

                }

            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);                
            }

            #region Print Table Schema

            foreach(DataRow field in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                foreach(DataColumn property in schemaTable.Columns)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",field[0],//HERE!); 
                }
            }            

            #endregion

            return schemaTable;

        }
```

At the line I marked (**HERE!**) I want to print the column's name and a boolean whether it is `allow NULL`. But all I get from field is an `itemarray[]`. I am sure that one of the values the array contains shows the `allow NULL` value. I can not figure out which one it is. Besides I think there must be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
Console.WriteLine(property.ColumnName +" = "+ field[property].ToString());
```

[AllowDBNull Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether null values are allowed in this column for rows that belong to the table.

Comment: The first column in my SQL table is ID which does not allow NULL. When using your solution the Console prints ID - true for each column in the table!

Comment: So I have the solution I was looking for and it looks as follows: Console.WriteLine(property.ColumnName +" = "+ field[property].ToString()); :Please modify your post and I will mark it as awnser.

Comment: @bodycountPP have updated, but not sure how that checks for nulls?

Comment: It at least shows me where to look for AllowDBNULL value. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

DataColumn has an `AllowDBNull` property.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.datacolumn.allowdbnull%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Assuming the ODBC driver in question is returning the Schema table appropriately, this should give you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT column_name, is_nullable FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = ?
```